# How to make a simple HTML file a useable page in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Hey going to keep this simple so please just ignore or answer,

I want to know if its possible to get a simple HTML page with some jscript functions and use it as a landing page or any other page for my wordpress website. My aim is to make a form which changes a few values on another page using javascript but i need the simplicity of a wordpress login for data protection.

is it possible to add in an html file and jscript files to wordpress through server? without needless complications or is there an easy way to make a simple log in form and i mean SIMPLE so that i am able to add security to the form page whilst keeping the page that is on display available.

EXAMPLE:

drop down menu with names of pictures is the form page, using form and when i submit the picture "Flower" it will update the page to display a flower

Answer (score 0):

So I am a bit confused by what you are trying to do but here is my crack at helping :) Also if my answer isn't suitable, do comment and rephrase the questions so I can try to help you further.

For your simple login page that you wanted to create...Here is a tutorial, very basic and easy to understand. Also source code is available on Github so you can tinker around with.

[Login Form](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-login-form.html)

Next, I personally do not use WordPress and simply develop my websites manually in conjunction with an external database and server. However, from what I gather, WordPress is merely a dashboard to view and manage your page, and wont house any physical files that would be your website (i.e php files, html files, css files, etc). Hence you will need to get a web host (server) to house all the data and actually see your website on the internet.

Here is a link to a free web host(server) called WAMP(MAMP if you are Mac user). Most people use this for developmental purposes (Your site is not technically live...this is just a tool to emulate a server). The link shows you how to connect WordPress to this server and you can begin to develop.

I hope this answers something...Feel free to comment and I will try to help as much as I can!

I used something similar in a project to control who can view what pages through php in my html page that detected and authorised the page based on login...so if the person is not the admin in your case they don't see that and you can add a link to redirect to the second page:

```
<?php
                        /*
                            Allow users
                        */
                     $REMOTE_USER = $_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"];
                    //$REMOTE_USER = 'admin';
                    if ($REMOTE_USER =='admin') 

                    {

                    }
                    else {echo "You are not authorised to view this page";
                    exit();}
?>
```

You can create and store the login created by the login form and put this code in all the pages relevant.

[Wordpress -> WAMP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHMV6tUuadA)

Comment: Hey sorry i didnt make things super clear, i have a website online but just wanted to know if i could pass an HTML file to the server and use it through wordpress. I use WAMP alot but as i am doing this with a live site i wont need it but thanks. 

I might end up just using the simple login form to secure the page that acts as the editor for the page that will be displayed.

Comment: Ill try better explain here

Page 1 is an admin page that has the ability to edit the output of page 2 it changes the content displayed on page 2 by using a form. I dont want page 1 to be accessed by anyone and only the 1 person  who has the username and password but page 2 can be viewed by anyone who has the url.

Comment: @user3755900, Check the edit I posted...that should help with the controlling of pages based on users linked with your form...Try posting some code of what you've got so I can get a better view to help.